# TX packets error & Collisions

Tags: networking, firewall

I am seeing a lot of collisions and errors on a WAN port (Sophos SG210) which connects to fiber NTU ( Cisco ME 3400E)

This is 100Mb up/down fiber but I am getting around 60Mb download and 3Mb upload. I think the cause of the slow upload speed is because of the packet collisions and errors.

I get around 70Mb/70Mb when I connect my laptop directly to the NTP.

What would be the cause of the problem?

Here is ifconfig on the WAN link on SG210.

```
eth1   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:110.xxx.xxx.xxx Bcast:110.xxx.xxx.xxx Mask:255.255.255.252
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:373271 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:220080 errors:2306 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2306
          collisions:128842 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:527821557 (503.3 Mb) TX bytes:48346583 (46.1 Mb)
```

ethtool eth1

```
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                              drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an interface operating in Half Duplex mode, which is the likely cause of the collisions.

Comment: How can I change this? and which port needs the configuration?

Comment: Well... which port did you post the configuration for? That's the port that needs it. Did you even read your own question? How to do it is a matter for the documentation.

Comment: The configuration is on the Sophos WAN port. Do both ports need to set full duplex? because I do not have access to the Cisco NTP as it is managed by ISP.